# Homomorphisms from $\textrm{Af}_1(\mathbb{R})$ to $(\mathbb{R}, +)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism, semidirect-product

I've been trying to get a more intuitive feel for semi-direct products (in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352540/the-geometry-of-the-action-of-the-semidirect-product) spirit), and to do so, have been trying to understand what a homomorphism from $\textrm{Af}_1(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}^+ \rtimes_\phi \mathbb{R}^\times$ (where for each $b \in \mathbb R^\times$ the automorphism $\phi_b$ of $\mathbb R^+$ is given by $a \mapsto ab$) into $\mathbb{R}$ looks like, as opposed to say a homomorphism from the direct product of these groups into $\mathbb{R}$.

Any such homomorphism restricts to the natural log (up to a scalar multiple) along the subgroup $\{0\}\times\mathbb{R}^\times$, and restricts to addition (again up to a scalar multiple) along $\mathbb{R}^+ \times \{1\}$, but I'm less confident how to leverage these observations to describe a general homomorphism when there's the 'twist' than I would be in the direct product case. How would I use this to characterize such homomorphisms?

> **Edit**: In particular, I'd be more interested in *continuous* homomorphisms, where both groups carry their usual euclidean topologies.

Comment: Well, indeed any homomorphism $\varphi$ from ${\rm Af}_1(\Bbb R)=\{x\mapsto a+bx:a\in\Bbb R,\,b\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}\}$ is determined by its values $\varphi(x\mapsto ax)$ and $\varphi(x\mapsto x+b)$ but if we only require an Abelian group homomorphism, then even these values can behave strangely: namely, we can also compose your proposals with any $\Bbb Q$-linear map $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Berci I edited the question to restrict to only continuous homomorphisms, regarding that later point to rule out weird $\mathbb{Q}$-linear functions. Re: the first point, are you saying that every (continuous) homomorphism is just described as a 2-vector then like in the direct sum case?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, there indeed should be some further connection between the base values.

Comment: I agree. It seems intuitive it should be something that reflects the structure brought to the table by $\phi$.

Comment: I've edited your description of $\phi$, which was somewhat abbreviated.